# Find no data values inside the extent of a shapefile and discarding the values outside the extent

Tags: raster, shapefile, clip

I have Randolph Glacier Inventory boundary shapefiles of glaciers in Himachal Pradesh. I clipped three different rasters with these shapefiles, and then stacked them together . these clipped rasters contain no data values and I have to find the no data values and the pixel values inside these rasters. But when I am extracting the raster, the values am getting are more than that they should be.

For example, the area of a glacier / shapefile is 8.719 km. sq and the resolution of raster is 10 sq.m  so accordingly number of pixel in the raster should be 87190, but I am getting approx. 333233(that may be because of the bounding box). So, I decided to create a binary mask so that I can get the values inside the boundary of the raster but still I am getting a lot more values than 87190.

The stacked raster all have the same resolution and the same extent but still when I extract them and multiply the extracted array with the mask given below, the number of pixels extracted are different for two bands.
the code i used for making the binary mask is given below .
I want to write a code so that I can extract pixel values inside(only inside the boundary of the shapefile) the raster with the no data values present within them.

[this is the mask I created](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q8z5T.png)
[this is the shapefile of the same glacier](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0IXaD.png)

```py
from rasterio.plot import reshape_as_image
import rasterio.mask
from rasterio.features import rasterize
from shapely.geometry import mapping, Point, Polygon
from shapely.ops import cascaded_union
shape_path=  "\glaciers of lahaul spiti clipped\RGIId_RGI60-14.11841/11841.shp"
glacier_df = gpd.read_file(shape_path)
raster_path =('/glaciers of lahaul spiti clipped/RGIId_RGI60-14.11841/stack9/raster_stack_sv_srtm.tif')
with rasterio.open(raster_path , "r") as src:
    raster_img = src.read()
    raster_meta = src.meta
    print("CRS Raster :{} , CRS Vector{}". format (glacier_df.crs , src.crs))
    def poly_from_utm (polygon,transform):
    poly_pts = []

    poly = cascaded_union(polygon)
    for i in np.array(poly.exterior.coords):
        poly_pts.append(~transform* tuple(i))

    new_poly = Polygon(poly_pts)
    return new_poly    
    poly_shp  = []
    im_size = (src.meta['height'] , src.meta['width'])
    for num , row in glacier_df.iterrows():
       if row['geometry'].geom_type == 'Polygon':
          poly = poly_from_utm(row['geometry'] , src.meta['transform'])
          poly_shp.append(poly)
        else:
           for p in row['geometry']:
              poly= poly_from_utm (p , src.meta['transform'])
              poly_shp.append(poly)

    mask_stack_sv_srtm = rasterize(
        shapes=poly_shp,
        out_shape=im_size
    )
    plt.figure(figsize = (5, 5))
    plt.imshow(mask_stack_sv_srtm)
```